# Передача файлов NIO2

Tags: java, nio2

Добрый день есть код

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT);
SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open();
socketChannel.connect(socketAddress);

FileChannel fileChannel = new RandomAccessFile(file, "r").getChannel();
fileChannel.transferTo(0, fileChannel.size(), socketChannel);
```

как я понимаю он для передачи файла. Нужен соотвецтвующий код со стороны получателя. Еще хотел спросить можно таким способом передавать видео, картинки, архивы. Если нет то дайте пожалуйста ссылку на ресурс где об этом можно прочесть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сервер принимающий файл:

```
public class NioServer {
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "image.jpg";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try (ServerSocketChannel serverSocketChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open()) {
            serverSocketChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(PORT));
            try (SocketChannel socketChannel = serverSocketChannel.accept()) {
                try (FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(FILE_NAME), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE)) {
                    fileChannel.transferFrom(socketChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Клиент передающий файл:

```
public class NioClient {
    private static final int PORT = 1234;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "image.jpg";

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        InetSocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT);
        try (SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(serverAddress)) {
            try (FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(Paths.get(FILE_NAME))) {
                fileChannel.transferTo(0, fileChannel.size(), socketChannel);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Таким способом можно передавать видео, картинки и архивы.

Comment: Добрый вечер, моя задача сделать возможной передачу файлов с сервера клиенту и обратно. Я дописал ваш код, если запускать код по отдельности (передать файл с сервера -> клиенту после отдельно запустить передачу (клиент -> серверу). Все работает нормально. Но с совмещением у меня не задалось. Как я понимаю на стороне сервера и клиента код который отвечает за принятие файла должен быть в отдельном потоке в обоих классах. Код передачи файлов в обеих классах так же должна быть в отдельных потоках. Из за дубляжа строк перекрывает поток. И сам код дублируется. Подскажите как это можно исправить ?

Comment: Задайте новый вопрос, опишите подробно, чего пытаетесь добиться и что не получается.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Клиент, передающий файл:

public class NioClient {
    private static final int PORT = 8189;
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "image.jpg";
  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        InetSocketAddress serverAddress = new InetSocketAddress(HOST, PORT);
        try (SocketChannel socketChannel = SocketChannel.open(serverAddress)) {

            RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("image.jpg", "rw");
            FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();
            ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

            int bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
            while (bytesRead > -1) {
                buffer.flip();
                while (buffer.hasRemaining()) { 
                    socketChannel.write(buffer);
                }
                buffer.clear();
                bytesRead = channel.read(buffer);
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Данный код работает в связке с кодом сервера, принимающего файл, предоставленный @Sergey Gornostaev.